# Event registering for Ajax / Jquery get() loaded image

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to load data into one content area of a JQuery-UI Accordion menu using get() method of Jquery. It is loading a group of images also.

```
$( "#accordion" ).on( "accordionactivate", function( event, ui ) {
$.get( "testb2.php")
.done(function( data ) {$('#rec1').html(data);});
});
```

Now the problem is the following code is not working on the loaded images.(Probably because the images were not present at the time of event registering process)

```
$("img").click(function(){

alert();
});
```

So what is the process to registering click events to Ajax loaded/jquery get() loaded images/buttons? Shall I have to call bind() method after loading all the images? in that case how?

Comment: Use `jQuery.on`, attach the event to the existing parent of the img's like so `$('.parent_div').on('click', 'img', function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

First use [**jQuery load**](https://api.jquery.com/load/), change this code

```
$.get( "testb2.php")
.done(function( data ) {$('#rec1').html(data);});
});
```

to

```
$('#rec1').load("testb2.php");
```

Then select the closest parent to the images that is initially present on the page

```
$('parent_div').on('click', 'img', function(){
    //handle click event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ya try the suggested approach given by @UnLoCo if still event is not registering than reload your related JS files dynamically using jQuery.getScript(-) function it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks. I checked  UnLcCo 's code first as he was first to answer. his code is working very good. All other answers are almost same an helped me a lot.